# android.graphics.Matrix -> How does postScale work

Tags: android

Good afternoon,

Lets say I have a Matrix. I have 2 values, .9 for zooming out and 1.1 for zooming in.

When I apply the `matrix.postScale(0.9, 0.9);` 3 times 
Then I apply the `matrix.postScale(1.1, 1.1);` 3 times

I am not back where I started!!

for example, here are the results I recorded:

Current Scale      postScale (x, x) Resulting Scale

```
1                  .9               .9
.9                 .9               .80999994
.80999994          .9               .7189999

.7189999           1.1              .8018999
.8018999           1.1              .8820899
.8820899           1.1              .97029895
```

As you can see I'm not back to 1. What is going on, am I getting the current scale incorrectly?

For example, to get all the values on the right, I preformed this after the postScale was applied:

```
matrix.getValues(tempArrayFloat);
Number = tempArrayFloat[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
```

I just assumed that the MSCALE_X and MSCALE_Y would be the same?

My question is, if I scale a matrix using 1 specific value 3 times, .9 -> .9 -> .9, what number do I need to scale it back to it's original position?

-Kind Regards,

Paul

Answer (score 7):

The numbers in the right hand side of your table give you your answer, a scaling matrix multiplies points by the scaling value. So applying `matrix.postScale(0.9)` three times scales by `0.9*0.9*0.9 = 0.729`. Applying `matrix.postScale(1.1)` three times scales by `1.1*1.1*1.1=1.331`. To get back where you started, you need to scale by `1.0/0.729=1.372`

Answer (score 2):

Scale it back by using 1.111111112 instead of 1.1, but if you are scaling a bitmap it may be easier to resize it to a round value.

Basically you could state `matrix.postScale(1.0/0.9, 1.0/0.9);` this should round it to the nearest pixel